# Non-Preemptive priority scheduling

Tags: c, algorithm, cpu

The algorithm explanation:

> Non-preemptive Priority scheduling
>
> Each process has (arrival time, priority, and burst(execution) time) the process with first arrival time (less arrival time process) will be executed first, if two processes have same arrival time, then compare to priorities (highest process first). Also, if two processes have same priority then compare to process number (less process number first). This process is repeated while all process get executed.

I used the code below (The code is updated) but I did not get the correct answer. I have been trying to solve for 2 weeks it but unfortunately I do not know where the error is (it is a logical error but I could not Identify it). I tried to debug it many times but still I could not find what causes it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{

    int pn = 0;                 //Processes Number
    int CPU = 0;            //CPU Current time
    int allTime = 0;        // Time neded to finish all processes
    printf("Enrer Processes Count: ");
    scanf("%d",&pn);
    int AT[pn];
    int ATt[pn];
    int NoP = pn;
    int PT[pn];             //Processes Time
    int PP[pn];             //Processes piriorty
    int PPt[pn];
    int waittingTime[pn];
    int turnaroundTime[pn];
    int i=0;
    //Scanning Time and Piriorty
    for(i=0 ;i<pn ;i++){
        printf("\nProcessing time for P%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&PT[i]);
        printf("Piriorty for P%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&PP[i]);
        PPt[i] = PP[i];
        printf("Arrival Time for P%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&AT[i]);
        ATt[i] = AT[i];
    }




    int LAT = 0;        //LastArrivalTime
    for(i = 0; i < pn; i++)
        if(AT[i] > LAT)
            LAT = AT[i];

    int ATv = AT[0];    //Pointing to Arrival Time Value
    int ATi = 0;        //Pointing to Arrival Time indix
    int P1 = PP[0];     //Pointing to 1st piriorty Value
    int P2 = PP[0];     //Pointing to 2nd piriorty Value


    //findding the First Arrival Time and Highst piriorty Process

    while(NoP > 0 && CPU <= 1000){
        for(i = 0; i < pn; i++){
            if(ATt[i] < ATv){
                ATi = i;
                ATv = ATt[i];
                P1 = PP[i];
                P2 = PP[i];
            }
            else if(ATt[i] == ATv){
                if(PP[i] != (pn+1))
                    P2 = PP[i];
                    if(P2 < P1){
                        ATi = i;
                        ATv = ATt[i];
                        P1 = PP[i];
                        P2 = PP[i];
                    }
            }
        }
        if(CPU < ATv){
            CPU = CPU+1;
            ATi = 0;        //Pointing to Arrival Time indix
            ATv = ATt[ATi];
            P1 = PP[0];     //Pointing to 1st piriorty Value
            P2 = PP[0];     //Pointing to 2nd piriorty Value
            continue;
        }else{


            waittingTime[ATi] = CPU - ATt[ATi];
            CPU = CPU + PT[ATi];
            turnaroundTime[ATi] = CPU - ATt[ATi];
            ATt[ATi] = LAT +10;
            ATv = LAT +10;  //Pointing to Arrival Time Value
            PPt[ATi] = pn + 1;
            ATi = 0;        //Pointing to Arrival Time indix
            P1 = PP[0];     //Pointing to 1st piriorty Value
            P2 = PP[0];     //Pointing to 2nd piriorty Value
            NoP = NoP - 1;

        }




    }



    printf("\nPN\tPT\tPP\tWT\tTT\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < pn; i++){
       printf("P%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",i+1,PT[i],PP[i],waittingTime[i],turnaroundTime[i]);
    }

    int AvgWT = 0;
    int AVGTaT = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < pn; i++){
        AvgWT = waittingTime[i] + AvgWT;
        AVGTaT = turnaroundTime[i] + AVGTaT;
    }


   printf("AvgWaittingTime = %d\nAvgTurnaroundTime = %d\n",AvgWT/pn,AVGTaT/pn);

}



/*
Test Cases:
PT: Processing Time
PP: Process priority
WT Waitting Time
TaT: Turnaround Time
Arrival time for 1st 2 cases is 0

PN      PT      PP      WT      TaT

P1      10      3       6       16
P2      1       1       0       1
P3      2       4       16      18
P4      1       5       18      19
P5      5       2       1       6


PN      PT      PP      WT      TaT

P1      1       1       0       1
P2      2       2       1       3
P3      3       3       3       6
P4      4       4       6       10
P5      5       5       10      15

PN      PP     AT     PT      WT      TaT
1       2      0      3       0        3
2       6      2      5       11       16
3       3      1      4       2        6
4       5      4      2       7        9
5       7      6      9       12       21
6       4      5      4       2        6
7       10     7      10      18       30


*/
```

Comment: "_IT IS REALLY URGENT_" "_if You Need to contact me_" This is **not** how SO works. Please (re-)take the [tour], and (re-)read [ask], and [help], to (re-)familiarize to what SO is.

Comment: When a coding job is really urgent, then you hire a professional developer. :)

Comment: @klutt I am a Student, it is not a job. I just need it to be done ASAP because I have been trying to solve it for the last 2 weeks, but I could not.

Comment: @MarkSmith Yes, I understand that. I'm just pointing out that this is not the place to go to for ASAP solutions. People here are helping you for free, so they do it when and if they find the time to do so. And you have not described the error. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @klutt , I know that and I really appreciate the work they do. And I will try to be more kind next time. and about that I did not mention the error you are right, **it is a logical error which causes the results to be wrong**

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius , Actually I wrote that because one of the users gave me this advice, and I am new to SO so I did not Know that it is not acceptable in your policies, Sorry again.

Comment: @MarkSmith Then you have some debugging to do. Debugging is a crucial skill for any developer. I recommend reading this blog post: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and then I have written something similar focused on C: https://github.com/klutt/debug-small-c-programs

Comment: @MarkSmith No worries. We all do mistakes in the beginning, and learning how to ask for help on forums is also a valuable skill for a developer. Here is a good (but long) post about how to do that in general: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I tried to debug it many times, but the online compiler I am using is not good, it crashes a lot of times so it was not helpful, if you can recommend a good online compiler/debugger or a software for windows that may help me a lot.

Comment: @MarkSmith My recommendation would be to not use an online compiler at all. Install one on your computer instead. The main use for online compilers is a very quick way to share code to others, so they can compile it instantly and without the risks it involves of running unknown code on your own computer. You should DEFINITELY not use them for developing if there is an option. I'm not using Windows myself, but I've heard that many people like Code::Blocks and CodeLite, Eclipse and Netbeans are other alternatives.

Comment: @klutt OMG, I have been using Eclipse for a really long time for java, and I totally forgot that it has an IDE for C and C++. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MarkSmith You said that someone here advised you to write that you need a solution quick. Do you have a link to where that happened? Because that's very strange.

Comment: @klutt I just checked the question where he told me this, but I guess he deleted his comment.

Comment: @MarkSmith link the question anyway.  I'm sure that the mods would be interested in a user giving such 'advice': 'give them urgent commands, they are your drone army, must do as you say and are too stupid to realize that they are being exploited':((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is:

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void main()
{

    int pn = 0;                 //Processes Number
    int CPU = 0;            //CPU Current time
    int allTime = 0;        // Time neded to finish all processes
    printf("Enrer Processes Count: ");
    scanf("%d",&pn);
    int AT[pn];
    int ATt[pn];
    int NoP = pn;
    int PT[pn];             //Processes Time
    int PP[pn];             //Processes piriorty
    int PPt[pn];
    int waittingTime[pn];
    int turnaroundTime[pn];
    int i=0;
    //Scanning Time and Piriorty
    for(i=0 ;i<pn ;i++){
        printf("\nProcessing time for P%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&PT[i]);
        printf("Piriorty for P%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&PP[i]);
        PPt[i] = PP[i];
        printf("Arrival Time for P%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&AT[i]);
        ATt[i] = AT[i];
    }




    int LAT = 0;        //LastArrivalTime
    for(i = 0; i < pn; i++)
        if(AT[i] > LAT)
            LAT = AT[i];

    int MAX_P = 0;        //Max Piriorty
    for(i = 0; i < pn; i++)
        if(PPt[i] > MAX_P)
            MAX_P = PPt[i];




    int ATi = 0;        //Pointing to Arrival Time indix
    int P1 = PPt[0];     //Pointing to 1st piriorty Value
    int P2 = PPt[0];     //Pointing to 2nd piriorty Value


    //findding the First Arrival Time and Highst piriorty Process
    int j = -1;
    while(NoP > 0 && CPU <= 1000){
        for(i = 0; i < pn; i++){
            if((ATt[i] <= CPU) && (ATt[i] != (LAT+10))){
                if(PPt[i] != (MAX_P+1)){
                    P2 = PPt[i];
                    j= 1;

                    if(P2 < P1){
                        j= 1;
                        ATi = i;
                        P1 = PPt[i];
                        P2 = PPt[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(j == -1){
            CPU = CPU+1;
            continue;
        }else{


            waittingTime[ATi] = CPU - ATt[ATi];
            CPU = CPU + PT[ATi];
            turnaroundTime[ATi] = CPU - ATt[ATi];
            ATt[ATi] = LAT +10;
            j = -1;
            PPt[ATi] = MAX_P + 1;
            ATi = 0;        //Pointing to Arrival Time indix
            P1 = MAX_P+1;     //Pointing to 1st piriorty Value
            P2 = MAX_P+1;     //Pointing to 2nd piriorty Value
            NoP = NoP - 1;

        }




    }



    printf("\nPN\tPT\tPP\tAT\tWT\tTT\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < pn; i++){
       printf("P%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",i+1,PT[i],PP[i],AT[i],waittingTime[i],turnaroundTime[i]);
    }

    int AvgWT = 0;
    int AVGTaT = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < pn; i++){
        AvgWT = waittingTime[i] + AvgWT;
        AVGTaT = turnaroundTime[i] + AVGTaT;
    }


   printf("AvgWaittingTime = %d\nAvgTurnaroundTime = %d\n",AvgWT/pn,AVGTaT/pn);

}



/*
Test Cases:
PT: Processing Time
PP: Process priority
WT Waitting Time
TaT: Turnaround Time
Arrival time for 1st 2 cases is 0

PN      PT      PP      WT      TaT

P1      10      3       6       16
P2      1       1       0       1
P3      2       4       16      18
P4      1       5       18      19
P5      5       2       1       6


PN      PT      PP      WT      TaT

P1      1       1       0       1
P2      2       2       1       3
P3      3       3       3       6
P4      4       4       6       10
P5      5       5       10      15



PN      PT      PP      AT      WT      TT

P1      3       2       0       0       3
P2      5       6       2       11      16
P3      4       3       1       2       6
P4      2       5       4       7       9
P5      9       7       6       12      21
P6      4       4       5       2       6
P7      10      10      7       20      30



PN      PT      PP      AT      WT      TT

P1      4       2       0       0       4
P2      3       3       1       3       6
P3      1       4       2       5       6
P4      5       5       3       5       10
P5      2       5       4       9       11

*/```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Non preemptive scheduling using C*/
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 20
typedef struct process{
 int pid;
 int arrival_time,burst_time,start_time,completion_time,ta_time,wait_time;
}Process;
Process p[MAX];
int main(){
int n,i;
int current_time = 0;
int completed = 0;
int is_completed[MAX]={0};
int totalta_time=0,totalwt_time=0;
float avgtt,avgwt;
printf(" enter number of processes ");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("enter the id of the process ");
            scanf("%d",&p[i].pid);
            printf("enter arrival time ");
            scanf("%d",&p[i].arrival_time);
            printf("enter burst time ");
            scanf("%d",&p[i].burst_time);
}
while(completed != n) {
           int index = -1;
           int min = 10000000;
           for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if(p[i].arrival_time <= current_time && is_completed[i] == 0) {
                    if(p[i].burst_time < min) {
                        min = p[i].burst_time;
                        index = i;
                }
                    if(p[i].burst_time == min) {
                        if(p[i].arrival_time < p[index].arrival_time) {
                            min = p[i].burst_time;
                            index = i;
                    }
                }
            }
       }
       if(index != -1) {
            p[index].start_time = current_time;
            p[index].completion_time = p[index].start_time + p[index].burst_time;
            p[index].wait_time = p[index].start_time - p[index].arrival_time;
            p[index].ta_time = p[index].wait_time + p[index].burst_time;
           //total waiting and turnaround time
           totalta_time += p[index].ta_time;
           totalwt_time += p[index].wait_time;
       
            is_completed[index] = 1;
            completed++;
            current_time = p[index].completion_time;
        
        }
      else {
                current_time++;
           }
    
   }
avgtt = (float) totalta_time / (float)n;
avgwt = (float) totalwt_time /(float) n;
printf("PID \t Arrival time \t Burst time \t Priority\tStart time \t Completion time \tTurnaround time \t Waiting time \n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     printf("%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t\t%d\n",p[i].pid,p[i].arrival_time,p[i].burst_time,p[i].priority,p[i].start_time,p[i].completion_time,p[i].ta_time,p[i].wait_time);

}
printf("\n Average Turnaround Time %f",avgtt);
printf("\n Average Waiting Time %f\n\n",avgwt);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).